# Connecting to a remote database from a localhost computer using mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

So here is the situation.
I have a database on a remote server that gives out quizzes and scores for individual students...

I also have a local database which contains the students names and their respective groups.

What I want to do is to display the list of students per group then show the results of their scores from the remote database.. Is this possible??

Im currently running the script from my local computer using XAMMP like so
mysql_connect("REMOTE SERVER ADDRESS","USERNAME", "PASSWORD") or die("Could not connect to MySQL server!");

But all I get is Could not connect to MySql Server..

Comment: Does your remote server have IP restriction? Otherwise only localhost connections are allowed.

Comment: Could you give us more information on what kind of address you are using e.g. https address or ip, as well as check what **Niels** said above, and do you happen to be on the same network as your remote database server?

Comment: I don't think it does.... Or is it possible to do it vice versa like i'll just upload the script to the remote server then connect to my local computer database when I view the page??? And by the way im using IP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GRANT ALL ON database.* TO user@ipaddress IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

You should force a reload of the grant tables using:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: This is correct, you probably do not have access from your IP. Most installs default to only letting localhost/127.0.0.1 access the db. You may also find the option somewhere in the interface if this is through a hosting provider.

Comment: i see well i should check with our IT Guy then.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Remote+MySQL# I found useful this one myselt. When you haven't define access permissions to remote db using it's cpanel, then you cannot connect with it via the localhost from your PC.

You will find something like 'Add Access Host' in your hosting server cpanel and there you can add which IPs are you going to use to access from outside. There I used as "%.%.%.%" and that means I allowed every v4 IPs to access my database. Instead of  "%.%.%.%"  you can put your PC's IP(for example 51.254.230.178). As PC's IP gets changed frequently, then I used this because I cannot change it manually all the time by checking my IP every time I connected to the Internet.

Comment: Please, enhance your answer by adding more info about solution to the question