# connect to online database from localhost in php

Tags: php, connection

I have two databases

One of them is on local server and the other is online.

I want to connect both in localhost by PHP code.

How to define this prameters for this purpose? Is special configuration required on local server?

```
//database that is local
    define( "HOST", 'localhost' ) ;
    define( "DBUSER", 'root' ) ; 
    define( "DBNAME", 'name_db' ) ;  
    define( "DBPASS", '' ); 


      //database that is online
        define( "HOSTPM", 'localhost' ) ;
    define( "DBUSERPM", 'username' ) ; 
    define( "DBNAMEPM", 'name2_db' ) ; 
    define( "DBPASSPM", 'password' );  

$db = new  PDO('mysql:host='. HOST .';dbname='. DBNAME . ';charset=utf8', DBUSER, DBPASS);
        $dbpm = new  PDO('mysql:host='. HOSTPM .';dbname='. DBNAMEPM . ';charset=utf8', DBUSERPM, DBPASSPM);
        if (!$db) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
        if (!$dbpm) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
       }
```

Comment: localhost is your current machine. if you need to access a remote resource connect to it via IP or hostname.

Comment: ok! I tested by IP and hostname for remote connection but get error like this Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Do you people even read documentation before coming to SO ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you don`t have access to mysql server remotely

Check that answer to modify privileges : [connect to mysql server remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156522/connecting-to-a-remote-database-from-a-localhost-computer-using-mysql-and-php)

> GRANT ALL ON database.* TO user@ipaddress IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

You should force a reload of the grant tables using:

> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;