# Connecting to a remote mySql server from my local machine

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My main problem right now is that I can't connect to the remote mysql server while developing on my machine. I'm trying to update a website that was previously developed by someone I do not know. I've been editing the site on my local machine but I need to access data from the mysql database that it has been using. I have the username and password that the site uses to connect to the mysql server. I can connect to it through phpmyadmin but I would like to work locally without publishing my edits to the server.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156522/connecting-to-a-remote-database-from-a-localhost-computer-using-mysql-and-php) here in SO and I tried running the scripts in phpmyadmin using my pc's IPaddress but I keep getting

> Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

even though I'm 100% sure I'm using the password that I used to login to phpmyadmin. I tried creating a new user but the login I'm using doesn't seem to have a *Create User* privilege either.

I understand that the previous developer might have a different "admin" account that has all the privileges but I have no way of knowing either.

I am a C# developer but I'm really new to MySql. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Database servers are usually locked down so that they listen for client connections on the server's local private network interface only. You don't want it to be reachable from anywhere on the internet. You have two reasonable options -- use a VPN to tunnel to the remote LAN so that the MySQL server thinks you're local, or make a dump of the database and then load it on a local instance of MySQL so you can fiddle with it without worrying about damage.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a firewall issue.  phpmyadmin listens on port 80 by default, but mySQL listens on port 3306.  Please check the firewalls on your local PC (to make sure you can get out on 3306) and the server (to make sure you can get in on 3306).

Comment: Opening port 3306 inbound on the server is a really bad idea.

Comment: @AlexHowansky you're probably right.  iamnobody: a better way is to talk with your IT operations team and come up with a secure way for you to talk to the port that MySQL is listening on.  This may involve NAT / PAT the port to a non-default port and IP-restrict the ingress (and / or set MySql to listen on a non-default port), but that's between you and your ops team.

Comment: I ended up just making a copy on my local since the other alternatives are more cumbersome. I'm working on this alone so I don't have and IT team backing me up. Thanks for the input, everyone!